# Toggle Navigation Active Link

Tags: jquery, navigation

So what I bassically want to do is:

I click on the link About and the link About animates to a certain position on a page and stays there. When I click the link Portfolio, the link About animates to its "before" (default) position and the link Portfolio animates to a certain position on the page and stays there. When I click the link Blog, the link Portfolio animates back to its "before" (default) position, and the link Blog animates to a certain position on a page and stays there and so on...

I generally want to click on the link, it animates to a position and a content box appears on a certain position on the page, but my thoughts are I can do that with iframe showing and hiding.

For now I want to click a link and make it stay active and return it to its original position when I make another link active.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#about").click(function () {
        $("#about").animate({
            top: '200px'
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HaxS5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".menuitem").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '200px'
    }).siblings().css("top","");
  });
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HaxS5/1/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! And how can I make it animate to the original position, not just appear there?